# Should I delete my answer that's effectively a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I was typing an answer to a question that has just been posted a few minutes earlier. By the time I clicked Post, I realized that someone else had already answered and basically the said the same thing I did.

Since I'm not sure that my answer is adding any value, should I delete it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question ?  It might help provide context if there's slight differences in the answer

Comment: @hmedia1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999124/how-to-design-a-book-database-in-which-a-user-can-only-have-one-review-per-book

Comment: Well - surprisingly, my answer just got an upvote so I guess someone thought it added some value.

Comment: the question has been deleted

Comment: Is it just me or is the original question really poor as far as questions go? Not surprised it was closed / deleted, should never had been answered in the first place.

Comment: Agreed; please don't answer questions like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Personally, for the example given; I'd keep it, because it offers an alternative approach to the other answer, and provides a rationale too (as does the other answer).  This is helpful as users may relate to one more than another or be constrained by one or the other.

In the case of two answers being written at once, which is not uncommon - I would review if mine adds another angle, caters for another scenario (OS, version, platform, etc), or perhaps if it complements / suppliments the other answer.  If it does (or if I could edit it to provide this), having read the other answer, then I will.  Otherwise, if it's just literally a double up providing no value, then I'd delete it.

Comment: Agree, but keep in mind that there is potentially a race condition if both users decide to follow this advice (unlikely...) - make sure that there is at least one answer as result.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's a good point.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Trivial enough to fix if it happens. Refresh the page and undelete if the other answer is also gone.

Comment: @jpmc26 ...and then refresh to check if the other answer has also reappeared ;-)